# azure vm location default using command line?

Tags: azure, command-line, virtual-machine

I'm trying to use the azure command line to start a vm:

```
azure vm start myvmnamehere
```

But it's telling me:

```
No deployments were found
```

I'm guessing that I need to specify the location "West US"?

Answer (score 0):

`azure vm start` is going to start a virtual machine that you've already created, within a specific region. To do that, you'd first need to call `azure vm create`. You would first create your vm from an image in the gallery (and within a dns name, xxxxx.cloudapp.net). To see the images available to you, try running `azure vm image list`.

Also: don't forget to add `--ssh` or `--rdp` so you can have remote access, when calling `azure vm create`.

Jeff Wilcox blogged about this in more detail, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/07/03/using-windows-azure-with-the-command-line-tools-for-mac-and-linux.aspx).

Comment: This is for a vm that's already been created. So I can't use "azure vm start" unless I use "azure vm create" first?

Comment: Correct. Individual virtual machines may be started and shut down at any time. And that's what `azure vm start` and `azure vm shutdown` are for. The virtual machine needs to actually exist first, hence `azure vm create` (which is a one-time call for a given virtual machine).